# What's the meaning of this declaration?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I saw this one in one of the .h files provided by my professor for a project, but I'm  not too sure what this means.

```
int (*get_console_dev)(void);
```

Is it the same as

```
(int*) get_console_dev(void);
```

(a function named get_console_dev, which returns a pointer to an `int`?)

Thanks

Comment: http://cdecl.org/ and http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html should make short work of any other unknown declarations you come across.

Comment: If it's in a header, shouldn't it be declared `extern` or `static`?

Comment: @sepp2k No, why would it need to be `extern` ? And if it' `static`, why would you put it in a .h file? (since technically, nothing `static` can be used outside of the file

Comment: @user1508893 It'd need to be `extern` or `static` because otherwise, if multiple C files included the header, you'd have multiple definitions of `get_console_dev`, which is not allowed if the variable isn't `static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int (*get_console_dev)(void)` is a function pointer declaration. `get_console_dev` is a variable that can hold a reference to a function matching the specific signature.

```
int consoleFunction(void);

// ...

int (*get_console_dev)(void);

get_console_dev = consoleFunction;
```

This declaration is not the same as: `(int*) get_console_dev(void);`.

Check this with [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28%2aget_console_dev%29%28void%29).

Comment: What's the intention/advantage of declaring a function pointer? just so someone can set it to some value which you don't care about, since all you need is a function that returns an integer>

Comment: just one example: you want to setup a [_function callback_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29), e.g. to handle a GUI event. A function pointer allows you to reference the handling function, pass it to another function. Another: allows you to pass around a function in a data structure, i.e. a `struct` that has a function that operates on the data. [see also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)

Answer (score 7):

It's a function pointer that can point to a function returning `int` and taking 0 parameters; it's not equivalent to the second line you posted.

Answer (score 0):

int (*get_console_dev)(void);

This is Pointer pointer function with no parameter and return type as integer.

(int*) get_console_dev(void);

This is function with no parameter and return type as pointer of type integer.

Both are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Please read up function pointers. it is a pointer to a function that takes void (as argument) and returns integer